# Use single HTML file for SPA application in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

In Sails.js documentation [it's stated](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views#?what-about-singlepage-apps) that you can use a single HTML file, i.e. `assets/index.html` to serve a single page application.

However, it's not stated how to achieve that.

I've created the file and removed all configuration from `sails.config.views`, but now I'm getting a 404 when I try to access `localhost/foo/bar`.

How do I properly implement such a setup?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for SPA, you need to use frameworks like `Angular.js` or `Backbone.js`. I have created a github repo for you to start building a SPA with `sails` and `angular`.

[View Github Repo](https://github.com/mjzac/AngularDemo)

Comment: I'm an experienced Angular.js developer, the problem is not in the client code, but in framework's configuration. How do I tell Sails to serve this single HTML file for all `text/html` non-ajax requests?

Comment: exactly.  There is a `route.js` file in sails where  you can specify the routes. For initial connection to server, say the root url, you can specify to load a particular view, here an `html` file.

Comment: Great, one more question, when my controller(server side) response, he response for view, like a sails application without front end framework ? tx a lot.